# Rendering bootstrap components in EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have the following property in my `QuoteSalesRep` class:

```
[Display(Name = "Commision %")]
[UIHint("Percentage")]
public decimal CommisionPercentage { get; set; }
```

I would like to create an Editor template that would render anything with the `[UIHint("Percentage")]` like so:

[image]

Under ***Views/Shared/EditorTemplates*** I added Percentage.cshtml. I currently have the following code:

```
@model decimal

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
</div>
```

I am new to working with templates. What do I need to do to correct the above code so it renders the input-group properly for any property tagged with [UIHint("Percentage")]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you're missing is a generic way of generating the text input:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(), new { @class = "form-control" })
```